# Getting a single value from SQL with ADO.NET

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net, webforms

I am this far:

```
// Update status history if the current work flow item has a status
int workflowID = Convert.ToInt32(statusCode.SelectedValue);
string status = "select status from jm_accountworkflowdetail where workid = @workID";

SqlConnection sqlConnection2 = new SqlConnection(sqlDevelopment.ConnectionString);
SqlCommand sqlComm2 = new SqlCommand(status, sqlConnection2);

sqlComm2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@workID", workflowID);
```

The query will either return a value ('SOC', 'POS') or  ('') meaning it didn't have a status attached.

What I need to do is if the status is not empty then perform some other code.  But I'm not sure how to execute everything just to check if the status has a value or not.

Comment: Post the code where you are you actually executing the command.

Comment: @KarlAnderson I didn't add tat but as I am sure I can do it like I have done others with sqlComm2.EvecuteNonQuery();

Comment: You could use [ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx) on `sqlComm2` to get the value of `status` (I'm assuming that you're only expecting one row returned by your query). You'll need to cast the return of `ExecuteScalar` but after that you could check it for the values you're expecting....

Comment: `ExecuteNonQuery` will not return any data. For SELECT statements, you have to use `ExecuteScalar` or `ExecuteReader`.

Comment: @nkvu I will try that thank you, and yes only one response should ever be returned.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use `ExecuteScalar();`

```
 string statusReturned = "";
 int workflowID = Convert.ToInt32(statusCode.SelectedValue);

 using (SqlConnection sqlConnection2 = new SqlConnection(sqlDevelopment.ConnectionString))
    {
        string status = "select status from jm_accountworkflowdetail where workid = @workID";
        SqlCommand sqlComm2 = new SqlCommand(status, sqlConnection2);
        sqlComm2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@workID", workflowID);
        try
        {
            sqlConnection2.Open();
            var returnValue = sqlComm2.ExecuteScalar()
                if returnValue != null then
                  statusReturned = returnValue.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //handle exception
        }
    }
    return statusReturned;
```

For checking the string value, you could have:

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(statusReturned)) {//perform code for SOC or POS}
```

Comment: I used what you had prior to the update of your post and it works just well and I'm sure the update will work as well.  You guys are geniuses. :)

Comment: I've updated the outer code, to use the `using` statement, which will dispose of your connection, I can't see all of your code, so it's worth implementing that pattern if you haven't already done so.

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, if you are concerned about checking null and making some decisions for null values, you can use `IsNull` function in T-SQL. It basically returns a value if record is null. So your above code will become like this:

```
string status = "select IsNull(status,'NoStatus') from jm_accountworkflowdetail where workid = @workID";
```

And then after you are done with SQL, you will use `If Else` for `status`

```
If(Status == "NoStatus") {your code block}
```

Hope it helps.